# How can i set the label of a progress-4GL fill-in widget?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I don't know how to set the label of a fill-in widget. I tried to set it while i initialize it, later, edit the "labels" attribute, but nothing worked for me.

Comment: Mike’s answer shows a couple of ways to do it but if you post an example of your actual code you might get something more suited to your needs.

Answer (score 4):

```
ASSIGN fill-in-1:LABEL IN FRAME {&frame-name} = "test" .
```

or

```
DEFINE VARIABLE h AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN h = fill-in-1:HANDLE IN FRAME {&frame-name}  
       h:LABEL = "test" .
```